# Install "Mediocre DHX Gantt" : 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime' (In Apps)

Tags: module, odoo, gantt-chart, odoo-14

I am trying to install "Gantt chart" in Odoo in my projects and I got this error, anyone have a solution?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odooadmin/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odooadmin/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

[image]

Comment: Check the `date_end` field type in `project.task`

Comment: Thanks, but is there another solution without using Python?

Comment: The `date_end` is of type ``Datetime``. What changed the type of the field?

Comment: i have date_start = fields.Datetime('Start Date')

Comment: I can see from the log above that `date_end` is of type `Date`

Comment: When try to change to Datetime I get this error : Properties of base fields cannot be altered in this manner! Please modify them through Python code, preferably through a custom addon!

Comment: Odoo prevent yo from updating base fields attributes, Check under ``Technical > Database Structure > Models`` in `In Apps` field to see the modules inheriting `project.task` model

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error

Comment: I can see that `dhx_gantt` did not alter the field type. What did you change?

Comment: Ahh, yes is "Date" how can I change to "Datetime" or there is other solution?

Comment: Did you find the module that change the field type? Update your question with the `In Apps` field value